# Uploading CodeIgniter4 to Shared Hosting via cPanel

Tags: codeigniter, deployment, cpanel, shared-hosting, codeigniter-4

I used Composer to setup CodeIgniter4 in my local PC. And I have completed the development also.

The problem is, am trying to deploy this application to a Shared Hosting that has cPanel.

I have zipped the contents (except the spark and build files) to the `/public_html/` folder in my Shared Hosting. Because the primary domain points to this `/public_html/` and I can't change it.

The problem now am facing is, if I access `www.mysite.com/public`, it loads the site. But won't load if I access just the domain name `www.mysite.com`

My directory/file structure is as follows (in the server):

[image]

So I basically want the site to be served when I access just the domain. My second question is, from the screenshot I shared, is there any files or folders that is not required to be in the production server?

---

**EDIT:**

This is the `.htaccess` file in `/public_html/` that I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: in your htaccess: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Vickel I tried that, but didn't worked. I have edited my question to include the code

Comment: also check in your config/app.php: `public $baseURL = 'https://example.com/'`

Comment: @Vickel I was using .env file to define this. But updated the `config/app.php` file also. But didn't worked.

Comment: this is what I have: `DirectoryIndex /public/index.php 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]`

Comment: @Vickel when I tested it is working. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your `/public_html/.htaccess`:

```
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php  
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do it like this:

Put the files from the "public" folder into the "public_html" folder on the server.

For the other CI directories and files, create and place in a folder called "ci", at the root of the server, do not put them in "public_html" to be safe and nobody can access.

Your index.php will be in "public_html", now you change the variable "$pathsConfig" to this path.
$pathsConfig = FCPATH . '../ci/app/Config/Paths.php';

It should work...

Comment: Thank you . I will try. But was looking at something that won't need me to move files.

Comment: This is the actual correct answer